# Calculating percent of each row value in MySQL in a certain date range

Tags: mysql

I want to get the first 4 rows with the highest value in a certain date range of a table in a mysql database. So I can do it with this code line, for example:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) as month, amount from sales where date >='2014-01-01' AND date <='2014-12-31' ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 4
```

But I want to add a new column with the percentage of each value, I tried with this line:

```
SELECT MONTH(date) as month, amount, round(amount*100/sum(amount) ,1) as 'percent' from sales where date >='2014-01-01' AND date <='2014-12-31' ORDER BY `amount` DESC LIMIT 4
```

But it doesn't work. How can I get it? I'd like some help.

Comment: We are not here to reverse engineer your SQL query. You atleast should include some example data as ascii data table or provide a sqlfiddle,com.. And the expected results as ascii data table.. Because this question don't have a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) this question is likly to be voted closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it. Providing snippets of raw data also helps. Creating an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) helps even more!!

```
select month, amount, round(amount*100/total,1) as percent
  from 
  (
    select MONTH(date) as month, amount 
      from sales 
      where date >='2014-01-01' AND date <='2014-12-31'
     ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 4
  ) c JOIN (
    select sum(amount) as total
      from sales 
      where date >='2014-01-01' AND date <='2014-12-31'
  ) t
```